# Doctrine : impossible to catch an exception when mysql server is down

Tags: php, mysql, exception, database-connection, symfony4

i'm using doctrine-bundle 2.9 in a 4.4 symfony project and want to handle an exception when mysql server is down. When i go in a specific Route on which database is needed, i'm having an exception thrown of type ConnectionException with message :

**An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Aucune connexion n'a pu être établie car l'ordinateur cible l'a expressément refusée.**

I tried (Any exception):

```
try {
 // use of repository or manager
} catch (Exception $e) {}
```

I am wondering if the higth level function (in repository for exemple) does not throw any exception.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Import and Try catch (ConnectionException $e)

Comment: I tired with ConnectionException and it not caugth even with Exception it does not catch the exception ..